# ceph runtime config is not the same with ceph.conf

Tags: runtime, ceph

i am using ceph-deploy to deploy ceph cluster. after deployment is finished, i found the runtime config is not the same with ceph.conf. i did not modify the runtime config in manual.

```
[root@sz02 ~]# ceph daemon osd.0 config show | grep rbd_cache
"rbd_cache": "true",
"rbd_cache_writethrough_until_flush": "true",
"rbd_cache_size": "33554432",
"rbd_cache_max_dirty": "25165824",
"rbd_cache_target_dirty": "16777216",
"rbd_cache_max_dirty_age": "1",
"rbd_cache_max_dirty_object": "0",
"rbd_cache_block_writes_upfront": "false",
[root@sz02 ~]# cat /etc/ceph/ceph.conf | grep "rbd cache size"
rbd cache size = 268435456
```

we can see that rbd_cache_size is different. so i want to know:

whether ceph runtime config reads the value from ceph.conf or not? if not, what's the meaning of ceph.conf?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

An OSD while it's starting reads /etc/ceph/ceph.conf and applies found parameters from this file to its runtime config. If it doesn't find some parameters, it uses the default values described in the docs. So the setting `rbd cache size = 268435456` **should** take an effect.

You can do the following:

1. Restart the osd daemon.
2. Check that the setting `rbd cache size = 268435456` is under `[client]` config section in your ceph.conf.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to restart the daemon:

```
ceph tell osd.0 injectargs '--rbd_cache_size=268435456'
```

but it's suggested to change it on all osds:

```
ceph tell osd.* injectargs '--rbd_cache_size=268435456'
```